# Cmake project link with alternate Qt framework path

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cmake

I'm trying to build a shared library (a plugin for DAZ Studio). I'm working on OS X with multiple versions of the Qt4 frameworks installed. One of them is a full install, the other  (the one I want to link against) has the frameworks, include files, and moc (no qmake).

I've cobbled together a CMakeLists.txt and it works for everything but the link. During the link phase, cmake insists on looking in /Library/Frameworks first, and I can't figure out how to tell it differently.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt. It's probably incorrect, or inefficient in many different ways (feel free to make additional suggestions).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 
project(SDK_CustomElements)            
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(DAZSTUDIO /Users/esemwy/DAZStudio4.5_SDK)
set(DAZ_PLATFORM_NAME Mac64)

set(LIB_SOURCE mycustommaterial.cpp mycustommodifier.cpp mycustomnode.cpp mycustomshape.cpp pluginmain.cpp)
set(LIB_HEADER mycustommaterial.h mycustommodifier.h mycustomnode.h mycustomshape.h)
set(LIB_VERSION version.h)
set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH TRUE)


set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "${DAZSTUDIO}/include")
set(CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH "${DAZSTUDIO}/lib/${DAZ_PLATFORM_NAME}") 

link_directories("${DAZSTUDIO}/lib/${DAZ_PLATFORM_NAME}")
include_directories("${DAZSTUDIO}/include")

set(DZCORE_LIBRARY     "${DAZSTUDIO}/lib/${DAZ_PLATFORM_NAME}/libdzcore.dylib")
find_library(QTCORE_LIBRARY     QtCore     )
find_library(QT3SUPPORT_LIBRARY Qt3Support )
find_library(QTGUI_LIBRARY      QtGui      )
find_library(QTNETWORK_LIBRARY  QtNetwork  )
find_library(QTOPENGL_LIBRARY   QtOpenGL   )
find_library(QTSCRIPT_LIBRARY   QtScript   )
find_library(QTSQL_LIBRARY      QtSql      )
find_library(QTXML_LIBRARY      QtXml      )
find_library(OPENGL_LIBRARY     OpenGL     )
mark_as_advanced(QTCORE_LIBRARY QT3SUPPORT_LIBRARY QTGUI_LIBRARY QTNETWORK_LIBRARY QTOPENGL_LIBRARY QTSCRIPT_LIBRARY QTSQL_LIBRARY QTXML_LIBRARY OPENGL_LIBRARY)
set(EXTRA_LIBS ${DZCORE_LIBRARY} ${QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT3SUPPORT_LIBRARY} ${QTGUI_LIBRARY} ${QTNETWORK_LIBRARY} ${QTOPENGL_LIBRARY} ${QTSCRIPT_LIBRARY} ${QTSQL_LIBRARY} ${QTXML_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY})

find_package (Qt4 REQUIRED)
include (${QT_USE_FILE})
set(QT_LIBRARY_DIR )

add_library(SDK_CustomElements SHARED ${LIB_SOURCE} ${LIB_HEADER_MOC} ${LIB_VERSION})   
target_link_libraries(SDK_CustomElements ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${EXTRA_LIBS})
```

Here's the link command it generates:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk  \
    -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names    \
    -o libSDK_CustomElements.dylib -install_name libSDK_CustomElements.dylib  \
    CMakeFiles/SDK_CustomElements.dir/mycustommaterial.cpp.o  \
    CMakeFiles/SDK_CustomElements.dir/mycustommodifier.cpp.o  \
    CMakeFiles/SDK_CustomElements.dir/mycustomnode.cpp.o  \
    CMakeFiles/SDK_CustomElements.dir/mycustomshape.cpp.o  \
    CMakeFiles/SDK_CustomElements.dir/pluginmain.cpp.o  \
    CMakeFiles/SDK_CustomElements.dir/SDK_CustomElements_automoc.cpp.o  \
    -F/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/esemwy/DAZStudio4.5_SDK/lib/Mac64   \
    -L/Users/esemwy/DAZStudio4.5_SDK/lib/Mac64 -framework QtGui -framework QtCore  \
    /Users/esemwy/DAZStudio4.5_SDK/lib/Mac64/libdzcore.dylib  \
    -framework QtCore -framework Qt3Support -framework QtGui -framework QtNetwork  \
    -framework QtOpenGL -framework QtScript -framework QtSql -framework QtXml  \
    -framework OpenGL
```

And here's how I generate it.

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5
```

At the base of it, all I think I really need to do is find a way to prepend to CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH, but nothing I try works. Swapping the order of the -F parameters produces a plugin with the proper library paths (otool -L).

When cmake does the link, I get:

```
QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.5)
QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.5)
...
```

When I link manually, I get:

```
@rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.1)
@rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.1)
...
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.